# Buscar en un DataGrindView con Dato Incompleto

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, c#-8.0

El código que tengo hasta el momento me busca un Dato "X" en mi **DatagridView**... y pinta la fila si encuentra el resultado. Pero no me encuentra el resultado si no completo la palabra o que este tal cual escrito en el **DatagridView**... Por ejemplo:

Quiero buscar el nombre de una persona... En mi **DataGridView** en la columna **Nombre** se encuentra **Jesus Emanuel Castran Perez** y si solo busco **Jesus Emanuel** sale sin resultados la búsqueda... Me gustaria saber si se puede hacer algo como cuando se busca en una Base de Datos colocando **'LIKE' NOMBRE '%'** ya que intente algo por el estilo pero no funciono.

Dejo el código a continuación:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows)
        {
            Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            String strFila = Row.Index.ToString();
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in Row.Cells)
            {
                string Valor = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);
                if (Valor == this.BuscarEnDGB.Text)
                {
                    resultadosdelaconsulta.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(strFila)].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo de dato `string` tiene el método [`Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netcore-3.1) que devuelve verdadero cuando el string que buscas es encontrado.

La forma de utilizarlo es la siguiente

```
...
if (Valor.Contains(this.BuscarEnDGB.Text))
{
    resultadosdelaconsulta...
}
...
```

Vale mencionar la existencia de los métodos:

- [`String.StartsWith()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netcore-3.1), para busquedas del tipo 'comienza con'
- [`String.EndsWith()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=netcore-3.1), para busquedas del tipo 'termina con'